# How do I add a blank line in the algorithmic environment?

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I'm trying to learn the [`algorithmic`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms_and_Pseudocode) package for typesetting pseudocode. One problem I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to insert blank lines, to separate blocks of code. The usual `\\` or starting a new paragraph doesn't seem to work. How can I insert blank lines in in the `algorithmic` environment?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want the empty line to be numbered, just insert

```
\STATE
```

on this line.

If you want an unnumbered empty line, insert

```
\item[]
```

instead.

Comment: But the lefthand label number increments by 1 as usual. Any way to introduce a new line WITHOUT incrementing the number?

Comment: I recommend the package `algorithmicx` which provides a set of macros to extend package `algorithmic` and is more customizable than the latter). Using `algorithmicx`, a blank line can be produced by \State (numbered) or \Statex (unnumbered).

Comment: When I add `\STATE` or `\item[]` before a `\COMMENT` line, then it doesn't work. I need to add it twice in order to see the same effect.

Answer (score 6):

just add

```
\texttt{\\}
```

it always works for me!!

Answer (score 2):

It’s a kludge, but you might be able to use

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{}
\begin{algorithmic}
    \STATE $x \leftarrow 1$
    \COMMENT{}
    \STATE $x \leftarrow 2$
\end{algorithmic}
```

Comment: This didn't work in an algorithmic environment for me.

Comment: Thanks. I added `\[\]` to algorithm and the line now is unnumbered.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `\[\]` instead of `\\`. Math formula is not numbered as a single line in `algorithmicx`.

Comment: What is the reason behind that? Why this would unnumber a line?

Comment: Thank you. \begin{algorithm}\end{algorithm}. I tried that on algorithm and it works!