# How to achieve proper formatting with minipage and algorithmic packages

Tags: minipage, multicolumn, algorithmic

Following this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53544/divide-the-page-into-2-parts), I used the solution in my document as follows but as you can see in the output, the algorithms do not start and end at the same levels. Is there a way I can make the algorithms start and end at the same level?

**EDIT** - It is OK if the algorithms don't end at the same level, I would just like them to start at the same level. If solutions exist for both scenarios, it would be great if you post them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{BLAH}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\ENSURE $A$.
\STATE
\STATE 
\STATE Set $AA$
\STATE 
\STATE
\STATE
\STATE
\STATE
\STATE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{BLAH}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE $Input$
\STATE Compute $B$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `'H` is not a float specifier out of the box. Why do you even have a float inside of a minipage? what is the purpose of this?

Comment: The algorithms were being used in a document without minipage initially. Now, I decided to use minipage to reduce document length. Following your comment, if I remove `H` from the code above, I receive errors. Also, are you just wondering my usage of `H` or did you just suggest a possible solution? Either way, not using `H` didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minipages have a `t` (top)  option, so in both minipages

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
```

produce this:

[image: mwe]

Comment: Is there an option to end them at the same level as well?

Comment: With respect to the minipages, yes: chage `[t]` by  `[t][8cm][t]` and put the minipages in a `\fbox{}` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to end the algorithms at the same level I can use the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28868/how-do-i-add-a-blank-line-in-the-algorithmic-environment) to add blank lines in the smaller algorithm i.e adding `\item[]` to the smaller algorithm will do